# How to add wrapper div on product page so that it includes related products sidebar?

Tags: product, layout, template, seo

I'm trying to implement schema.org microdata for rich snippets.

I can do that for the main product, easily. But I would like to tag the related products with the `isRelatedTo` property for the main product. The problem is that they must be contained in a child `div` of the main product `div`, and they are not.

I cannot do it in `view.phtml`.

Any ideas?

Also please help with tags for this quesiton. The only one I could think of was `seo`.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.
The main product is contained in the center section of the page and the related items are on a sidebar (left or right).  The center and the sidebar are inside separate elements.

But what you can do is to change your design and include the related products in the center section.

For this, edit `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/catalog.xml` and look for this inside the `catalog_product_view` layout handle:

```
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

Remove that and add this inside the block

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

The following code will move the related products block inside the content.

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related_products" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
```

Now edit `catalog/product/view.phtml` and add this line where you want the related products to be displayed.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products')?>
```

Now you can edit `catalog/product/list/related.phtml` and add your markup around the products listed there.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this as well for a webshop. If moving the related products into your product view (content) isn't an option, you can set the itemtype to your body, with a check if it's either a product page or a normal webpage. This works fine for me.

Of course you should recheck your rich snippets, mainly because of the prices that are in your page.